# Plotting two Poisson processes on one plot

Tags: r

I have two Poisson processes:

```
n <- 100
x <- seq(0, 10, length = 1000)
y1 <-  cumsum(rpois(1000, 1 / n))
y2 <- -cumsum(rpois(1000, 1 / n))
```

I would like to plot them in one plot and expect that `y1` lies above x-axis and `y2` lies below x-axis. I tried the following code:

```
plot(x, y1)
par(new = TRUE)
plot(x, y2, col = "red",
 axes = FALSE, 
 xlab = '', ylab = '', 
 xlim = c(0, 10), ylim = c(min(y2), max(y1)))
```

but it did not work. Can someone please tell me how to fix this? (I am working with R for my code)

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Unless you first use `plot` then `lines` or fix the ylimits, your two plots will not have the same y limits.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about

```
plot(x,y1, ylim=range(y1,y2), type="l")
lines(x, y2, col="red")
```

[image]

I would suggest trying to avoid multiple calls to plot with `par(new=TRUE)`. That is usually very messy. Here we use `lines()` to add to an existing plot. The only catch is that the x and y limits won't change based on the new data, so we use `ylim` in the first `plot()` call to set a range appropriate for all the data.

Comment: Usually the only reason for `par(add=TRUE)` is if one is using a base graphics `plot`-function with special features.

Comment: Yeah!! this is awesome, it works perfectly and I can even add more lines on it such as the line of the difference between `y2` and `y1`. Thanks @MrFlick !!

Answer (score 3):

Or if you don't want to worry about limits (like MrFlick mentioned) or the number of lines, you could also tide up your data and using `melt` and `ggplot`

```
df <- data.frame(x, y1, y2)
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)
mdf <- melt(df, "x")
ggplot(mdf, aes(x, value, color = variable)) +
  geom_line()
```

[image]